# Azure Table QuerySegmented no return

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to pull a group of entities from an AzureTable and am using the following code to query it.

```
string partitionKey = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:d20}", accountId);
string rowKeyStart = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:g", work.lead.id);
string rowKeyEnd = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:h", work.lead.id);

var context = table.ServiceClient.GetTableServiceContext();
var query = context.CreateQuery<LinkedInPostEntity>(table.Name)
        .Where(w => w.PartitionKey == partitionKey && w.RowKey.CompareTo(rowKeyStart) > 0 && w.RowKey.CompareTo(rowKeyEnd) <= 0)
        .AsTableServiceQuery(context);

List<PostEntity> postsForLead = new List<PostEntity>();
TableContinuationToken continuation = null;

do
{
    TableQuerySegment<PostEntity> segment = await AzureHelper.QuerySegmented(query, continuation);
    postsForLead.AddRange(segment.Results);
    continuation = segment.ContinuationToken;
} while (continuation != null);
```

`table` is an instance of CloudTable, `accountId` is an int, and `work.lead.id` is a string. I want to pull all entities which have a RowKey prefixed by that `work.lead.id:g` and followed by a string id. I feel like this code should work but it hangs on the `await` never finishing the `Task` given by QuerySegmented.

My thought might be that the Query is incorrectly formatted but I'm not sure how or why.

BTW I am new to posting so please let me know if I have forgotten any important information or can help clarify in anyway.

EDIT: here is very similar code that does work, its being called on a similar (though different) table which has a different id scheme. I need to use the id scheme given to me by the api I am using so I don't think reformatting it prior to entry is an option. The only difference between the two is the query so I have the feeling my query is to blame. Any ideas?

```
string partitionKey = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:d20}", accountId);
string rowKeyStart = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:{1:d20}", work.ScreenName, (long)0);
string rowKeyEnd = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}:{1:d20}", work.ScreenName, long.MaxValue);

var context = table.ServiceClient.GetTableServiceContext();
var query = context.CreateQuery<TweetEntity>(table.Name)
        .Where(w => w.PartitionKey == partitionKey && w.RowKey.CompareTo(rowKeyStart) >= 0 && w.RowKey.CompareTo(rowKeyEnd) <= 0)
        .AsTableServiceQuery(context);

List<TweetEntity> tweetsForLead = new List<TweetEntity>();

TableContinuationToken continuation = null;

do
{
    TableQuerySegment<TweetEntity> segment = await AzureHelper.QuerySegmented(query, continuation);
    tweetsForLead.AddRange(segment.Results);
    continuation = segment.ContinuationToken;
} while (continuation != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

My spidey-sense tells me that you're calling this method and then calling `Wait` or `Result` on the returned task, from an ASP.NET or UI context. [If you do this, you'll deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

Comment: Hmm seems like this might be the problem! Strange because it works for a different kind of query, let me look deeper into it before marking this as correct. Thanks very much though!

Comment: Hmm unfortunately it didn't seem to solve the problem. I had the chance to read your blog post and it seems like the context problem is only for UI applications. This code is being run inside of an Azure Worker Role so I don't think it falls victim to the same problem.

Comment: In that case, could you post a small yet complete repro?